# i have a blazor server application project and web api project in same solution...and i want to call the api endpoints from my blazor razor.cs file

Tags: blazor

Here is my razor.cs file and i want to call my api end point in load data function.

```cs
using Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace AdminReview.Pages.Media
{
    public class MediaBase : ComponentBase
    {
        protected int PageSize = 10;
        protected int PageNumber = 1;
        protected int TotalPages = 0;
        protected IList<MediaModel> MediaList = new List<MediaModel>();
        [Inject] protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            try
            {
                LoadData(PageSize, PageNumber, TotalPages);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void LoadData(int pageSize, int pageNumber, int totalPages)
        {
            //MediaList = Common.MediaInst.GetAllMedia(pageSize, pageNumber,totalPages).Items.ToList();
        }

        public async Task AddMedia(int id)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/mediadetails?id={id}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is incomplete, where/how do you call AddMedia() and do you really want to go to another page then?

Comment: i want to get media in LoadData method...i have created api for this but i dont know how to call the end point...

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly